# how to turn texts to be array by line with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, text

```
aaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccccccccc
dddddddddddddddddd
```

I want turn to be a array base on line like that

```
array(
0=>'aaaaaaaaaaaa',
1=>'bbbbbbbbbbbbbb',
2=>'ccccccccccccccccccc',
3=>'dddddddddddddddddd'

)
```

How to do it with php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = "aaaaaaaaaaaa 
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb 
ccccccccccccccccccc 
dddddddddddddddddd";
$array = explode("\n", $string);
```

Comment: This will still display as a single line in HTML, you need "$array = explode("\n<br\\>",$string)

Comment: It won't display as anything in particular; it'll make an array with the lines in it. Also, those <br/>s weren't there when I answered.

Answer (score 1):

```
$myArray = explode($your_seperator_string, $string_to_be_parsed_to_array);
```

PHP's [`explode(string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ])`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function splits a `string` by `delimiter`.

Comment: This assumes newline is the line ending.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = explode("\n", $str); // $str contains your text
```

Comment: Or `explode(PHP_EOL, $str);` to make it platform agnostic. But then, if he is reading it directly from a file, he should really use the [file()](http://php.net/file) function within PHP.

Comment: This assumes newline is the line ending.

Answer (score 1):

The following is pretty flexible about line endings (newline or carriage return), or can be modified to include any space.

```
$lines = preg_split('/[\r\n]/', $text);
```

However, if you know the line ending to be `\n` (newline) I would recommend `explode()` as it avoids the regex overhead.

```
$lines = explode("\n", $text);
```

Read more on [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) and [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode).

Comment: I was never very good at Pearl Regular Expressions, +1 for understanding them!

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, new lines are represented by `\n`.  Therefore, you can use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to create an array after each new line.

```
$string = "aaaaaaaaaaa
           bbbbbbbbb
           cccccccccccccccc
           ddddddddddd"

$string = "aaaaaaaaaaa\nbbbbbbbbb\ncccccccccccccccc\nddddddddddd"

//Both $string variables are the same

//Make sure that \n is in double quotes, single quotes WILL NOT WORK!!!
$array = explode("\n", $string);
```

There you go!   Feel free to use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and other similar functions with the `\n` to achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the split() method.
[PHP:split Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php)

```
$myArray = split("[\n|\r]", $string);
```

Depending on the system that created the original string, you may or may not need the \r.

Comment: This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

preg_split() is the recommended alternative.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://www.ideone.com/e9uiq)**

```
<?php

  $sample = "aaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccccccccc
dddddddddddddddddd";

$ary = array_map("trim",explode("\n", $sample));

var_dump($ary);
```

OUTPUT:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "aaaaaaaaaaaa"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "bbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "ccccccccccccccccccc"
  [3]=>
  string(18) "dddddddddddddddddd"
}
```

*I use trim in case they are either \r\n or \n separated. Can also use regex, but figure I'd offer one more solution and the `array_map` is optional.*

Answer (score 0):

```
$output_array = explode("\n<br />\n", $input_string);
```